# How to select an active Word document with a variable phrase in the file name

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm a state government worker and novice coder.  I'm trying to learn to code to make some tedious, error-prone work a little less so.

I have a prompt that opens when running a macro from an active Word document that I'll call Doc A:

```
strPrompt = "Please enter HD number and Draft." & vbCrLf & "Enter number only, followed by a space, then draft number with no spaces."
strHR = InputBox(strPrompt, "HR number and draft")
```

From here, I want Word to activate the Word document that contains "HR" & strHR in its file name (Doc B).

I then want to copy certain text from Doc B and paste it into Doc A.

I've read other posts here on how to copy text and paste it; just need to know how to tell Word to select the right Word doc (Doc B) to paste that text into.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please edit your question and include your code attempt then explain what's not working with your code.

Comment: It would make it a bit more 'on topic' for SO if you edit your code sample to show a full working [mcve] including what you have tried so far (even if it doesn't work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need something like the following:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim strPrompt As String, strHR As String
    strPrompt = "Please enter HD number and Draft." & vbCrLf & "Enter number only, followed by a space, then draft number with no spaces."
    strHR = "HR" & InputBox(strPrompt, "HR number and draft")
    Dim sourceDoc As Document
    Set sourceDoc = FindOpenDocument(strHR)
    If sourceDoc Is Nothing Then
        'document wasn't found
    Else
        'copy whatever you need from the document
    End If
End Sub

Function FindOpenDocument(findText) As Document
    Dim doc As Document
    For Each doc In Documents
        If InStr(doc.Name, findText) > 0 Then
            Set FindOpenDocument = doc
            Exit For
        End If
    Next doc
End Function
```